# How to submit a same form with different url?

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, django

In the click of button form will submit and the success data contains next_url. My goal is to submit the same form with next_url. Is this possible.? Sorry if the question asked already then give me the url.

My script code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '/',
      async: false,
      data: $("#form_to_submit").serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $('form').attr('action', data.next_url);
        $('form').unbind('submit').submit();
      }
    })
    return false;
  })
})
```

And sample django view here.

```
def home(request):
    data_dict = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_data = request.POST['data']
        data_dict['form_data'] = form_data
        data_dict['next_url'] = reverse('frontend:first_term')
        return JsonResponse(data_dict)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'data_list': data_list})


def first_term(request):
    data_dict = {}
    data_dict['next_url'] = reverse('frontend:second_term')
    return JsonResponse(data_dict)
```

**Update 1 :**

Above code is redirect to the `localhost.com/first_term` and with `{"next_url": "/second_term"}` context.

But I expected first_term will post the value and will get the next_url in success method [ `third_term` ]

Comment: Putting passive-aggressive "still waiting" messages on your post doesn't make people any more likely to answer. Don't do that. At the very least you need to explain what goes wrong when you use the code you have posted.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks... I edited the question.. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '/',
      async: false,
      data: $("#form_to_submit").serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
       cache: false
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('form').attr('action', data.next_url);
        $('form').unbind('submit').submit();
      }
    })

  })
})
```

or

[See the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/TfTwe/31/)

Comment: it redirect to the localhost:8000/first_term with the context of `{"next_url": "/second_term"}`